# Variable Ref in collection

Tags: vba, variables, collections, nested, ref

This is my problem.
i've just recongnized that collection are not a ref table of other variables. it look like an item added to a collection is not a ref in the collection but it has been "doubled" in a way.

```
Sub TestCollection()
'--------------------------------------------------------
' definition
Dim COLL As New Collection
Dim x As Double
Dim xr As Range
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Give a value to x and xr
Set xr = Range("A1")
x = 1
xr = 1
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Add to the collection
COLL.Add x, "x"
COLL.Add xr, "xr"
'--------------------------------------------------------
' First debug
Debug.Print "Original value of x and xr (range)"
Debug.Print COLL(1)
Debug.Print COLL(2).Value
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Change the value
x = 2
xr = 2
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Second debug
Debug.Print "Now vba will change x and xr (range)"
Debug.Print COLL(1)
Debug.Print COLL(2).Value
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Change the Ref on xr
x = 3
Set xr = Range("A2")
xr = 3
'--------------------------------------------------------
' Third debug
Debug.Print "Now vba will change x and xr (ref)"
Debug.Print COLL(1)
Debug.Print COLL(2).Value
'--------------------------------------------------------
End Sub
```

Debug-print values:

```
Original value of x and xr (range)
 1 
 1 
Now vba will change x and xr (range)
 1 
 2 
Now vba will change x and xr (ref)
 1 
 2
```

x an xr are not a ref in the collection but they are different object.

There is a possibility for having a collection of ref object as i wanted?

Comment: To be clear `xr` is a range, `xr = 1` is not reassigning `xr`, its calling `xr.Value = 1` only at `Set xr = Range("A2")` does `xr` change, there is no coupling with the `xr` that was added to the collection at this point as they are different things.  `x` will never change within the collection, its a value type and so is always copied on assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wording is strange, but I think I see what you're trying to do, and your answer is "nope". `x` isn't an object in the first place, so that one's out of the equation.

`xr` is an object reference, but when you added it to the collection what you've added is *a copy of the pointer to that object*.

So you have `xr` pointing to `[A1]`, and a collection item pointing to `[A1]` as well. If you do this:

```
Range("A1").Value = 2
```

Then I'd expect both `xr.Value` and `COLL("xr").Value` to output `2`, because both are pointing to that same object.

Except then you go and do this:

```
Set xr = Range("A2")
```

You've just discarded a *copy of the object pointer*, named `xr`, and now you have `xr` pointing to `[A2]`, and a collection item still pointing to `[A1]`. So when you do this:

```
Range("A2").Value = 3
```

You can't expect `COLL("xr").Value` to be `3`, because it's not a pointer to the same object anymore.

There's no way the collection could have known that the value it's holding at index/key `"xr"` needed to automagically start pointing to `[A2]` after you've re-assigned `xr`: that's just not how object references work.

Comment: Oh yes, you got the question and answered very well, explaining that all i do is just a _copy of the pointer.

But there's a way to get what i want? Another type of data?

Comment: It's not what *you* do, it's just how things work - regardless of what you do, a collection is always going to have a copy of the object reference.

Answer (score 2):

When you add xr to the collection *you're just adding a copy of the reference* - whatever you do to xr after that doesn't affect the copy in the collection.

Easier to follow:

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range

Set r1 = Range("a1")

Set r2 = r1 'make a copy of the reference
Debug.Print r1.Address(), r2.Address()
'>>            $A$1          $A$1

Set r2 = Range("a2")
Debug.Print r1.Address(), r2.Address()
'>>            $A$1          $A$2
```